# C# Simpler way to iterate thru display selects

Tags: c#, class, loops, methods

Newb here asking for help.

Currently I am being to work with classes, and to that end, i am using classes to print out 5 direct objects based on my class object of product.

This is the code to print out my items:

```
Console.WriteLine("1." + prod1.GetDetails() + "\n\n");
Console.WriteLine("2." + prod2.GetDetails() + "\n\n");
Console.WriteLine("3." + prod3.GetDetails() + "\n\n");
Console.WriteLine("4." + prod4.GetDetails() + "\n\n");
Console.WriteLine("5." + prod5.GetDetails() + "\n\n");
```

Looking at my code, it feels very redundant, as there are only two chars that change: the item number displayed in the first double quotes, and then the number which differentiates which 'prod' i am printing with my class object of product (I'm a newb, hopefully i am communicating this correctly).

I tried to create a method to iterate this out as that would be cleaner and scaleable, but my method isn'' working correctly.

My most current attempt:

```
public void DisplayOfferings()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++ )//prints items 1 to 5 
    {
      Console.WriteLine(i + ". " + prod(i).GetDetails() + "\n\n"); 
    }  //iterate number      
}
```

This is how i store my products which i'm trying to print, i have them at the class PROGRAM level so they are available to all functions as i'll use them a few time ulimately
class Program
    {

```
    Product prod1 = new Product("iPod Shuffle", "The clip-and-go iPod shuffle. With buttons, VoiceOver, and playlists, it's the best of iPod shuffle. Available in seven colors.", 49.89, true);

    Product prod2 = new Product("iPod Nano", "About the size of a credit card — and just 5.4 mm thin — iPod nano is the thinnest iPod ever made. Available in seven colors.", 149.89, true);

    Product prod3 = new Product("iPod Classic", "With 160GB of storage, iPod classic is the take-everything-everywhere iPod. Available in Silver or Midnight", 249.89, false);

    Product prod4 = new Product("iPod Red", "With 160GB of storage, iPod [RED] PRODUCT lets other fashion victims know you aren't just some mass consumer status concious drone, your a drone with a concious because Bono said so! Available in red.", 349.89, false);

    Product prod5 = new Product("iTouch", "It's just like an iPhone accept that your parents obviously don't trust you with a phone yet.", 449.89, true);
```

Comment: Edited the above to show how i'm storing/building the items/class objects to print.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to store your instances into a `List`:

```
var list = new List<YourType> { prod1, prod2, prod3, prod4,prod5 };
```

Then just loop through that list:

```
int i = 1;
foreach(var prod in list)
{
   Console.WriteLine(i + ". " + prod.GetDetails() + "\n\n"); 
   i++;
}
```

If you want to define a method for this, you can define it like this:

```
public void DisplayOfferings(List<Product> products)
{ 
    int i = 1;
    foreach(var product in products)
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(i + ". " + product.GetDetails() + "\n\n"); 
        i++;
    }
}
```

Then first create your list and call it:

```
var productList = new List<Product> { prod1, prod2, prod3, prod4,prod5 };
DisplayOfferings(productList);
```

In fact you can use [`params`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/w5zay9db%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) keyword here it makes your work easier.For example if you change your method definition like this:

```
public void DisplayOfferings(params Product[] products)
```

You can call it without defining a list:

```
DisplayOfferings(prod1, prod2, prod3, prod4,prod5);
```

Comment: I would rather use the classic `for` if you have to use a variable to increment (i) anyway.

Comment: I attempted this but i forbarded it. I list the method call like so "DisplayOfferings(Product[]);" and then attempted this for the method " public void DisplayOfferings(Product[] products)
        {
            var list = new List(Product[]) { prod1, prod2, prod3, prod4, prod5 };

            int i = 1;
            foreach (var prod in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i + ". " + prod.GetDetails() + "\n\n");
                i++;
            }
        }". I did some stuff wrong, not sure what. I'm a newb, but i'm glad to see this can be done even if i can't yet do it

Comment: @Chezshire first create your list then pass your method like this: `DisplayOfferings(productList);` and your list definition is wrong, don't use parentheses List(Product[]) instead use `new List<Product>`

Comment: Thank you, looking at everything here helped me to realize to pop my junk in an array, then do this "for (int i = 0; i < products.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(products[i].GetDetails());
            }

Comment: But i will be experimenting with your suggestions tonight :D THanks learned lots which is always my goal

Comment: Question: Do you really use the greater/lesser than symbols? I've not seen that used before in cSharp.

Comment: No, it's not symbols.It's c# syntax :) see [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f.aspx), `List<T>` is a generic class, and you have to use `'<'` and `'>'` characters when you defining a generic list or class.also you will use them when  calling the generic methods.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void DisplayOfferings(Product[] products)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= products.length; i++ ) 
    {
      Console.WriteLine(i + ". " + products[i - 1].GetDetails() + "\n\n"); 
    }      
}
```

where products is an array of prod1 ... prodN

Comment: did you mean `products[i - 1]` ?

Comment: Thank you for the help - you helped to spin me off in some really good ways. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

How do you come by these individual product objects? I'm assuming you're creating these 5 objects and testing the GetDetails() method? To make it cleaner, you can always create an Array/List of "product" objects and call the method as described below; again without sufficient data from you, I cannot figure out 1) how you obtained these products and 2) what you intend to do with them :-) -->

---

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        List<Product> products = new List<Product> 
                                        {   
                                            new Product("product 1"),
                                            new Product("product 2"),
                                            new Product("product 3"),
                                            new Product("product 4"),
                                            new Product("product 5")
                                        };
        /** do some more work here in this segment */

        // now call your GetDetails() method in a nicer Object Oriented (subjective) manner
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine("\"" + (i+1) + ".\"" + products[i].GetDetails() + "\n\n");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private class Product {
        public Product(string data) {
            Data = data;
        }

        public string Data { get; set; }

        public string GetDetails() {
            return "The initial data string is:\t" + Data;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just added how i'm storing the objects, hopefully i intuited what you are asking correctly. I'm a newb FYI

Comment: THanks for the help, i got it working. Now that i have it working i'm going to try all these other ideas - thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could always go down the LINQ path:

```
var list = new List<YourType>
{
    prod1, prod2, prod3, prod4, prod5
};

list
    .Select((prod, i) => String.Format("{0}. {1}\n\n", i, prod.GetDetails()))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Comment: I have no idea what LINQ is, but i think i know what I'll be looking into tomorrow - thanks